# Do Hindu Gods commit sin and go to hell? If yes please quote the scripture

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, gods, sin, evil

- because Krishna said that Gods are also trapped in the system of creation
- Krishna said He is the one who does all- both good and evil by incarnating himself.

Does it mean that when a bad guy is hitting a good guy, Krishna is playing both the roles?

Comment: Hindu gods commit sin but they do not go to hell. The reason is that the sin incurred is never a large sin. They know the rules very well.

Comment: They do commit sins and as a result, gets punished, one example is the 7 vasus, who were cursed to be born on earth, and during Mahabharata, Ganga gave birth to all of them and killed them (I hope you know the story), one more example is the twins who were cursed to remain as trees on earth and krishna freed them. All in all, They treat earth as there hell :D

Comment: Did Krishna, Shiva, Ram, Vishnu, or any other main Gods committed any sin and had to suffer for it?